# FireStore - Dealing with multiple onCreate() functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have implemented Stripe into my project. I am using Stripe Connect. Meaning I have two types of users. A customer and a vendor. These are my two functions:

```
exports.createConnectAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (vendor) => {
  const connectaccount = await stripe.accounts.create({
    type: 'express',
    email: vendor.email,
    country: 'GB',
    business_type: 'individual',
    default_currency: 'gbp',
    capabilities: {
    card_payments: {requested: true},
    transfers: {requested: true},
    },
  });
  await admin.firestore().collection('vendors').doc(vendor.uid).update({connectAccount_ID: connectaccount.id});
});
```

And creating a Stripe customer:

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
  await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).update({customer_id: customer.id});
});
```

The issue is whenever a customer signs up, the `createConnectAccount` is triggered as well. Meaning the customer will also create a vendor account unknowingly. Although this does not affect my app at all, it is just an unnecessary call.

Both the customer and vendor are stored in two different fields, within my database. But I suspect both are fired due to `functions.auth.user().onCreate`. Is there anyway in which I can point to the location of where an Auth user has been created? Such as `users` and `vendors`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Is there anyway in which I can point to the location of where an Auth user has been created?"  It looks like you've already built paths to documents in both collections using the user's ID.  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @DougStevenson Essentially, when a user is created I want the `createStripeCustomer` function triggered. When a vendor is created I want `createConnectAccount` to be triggered. Right now, any form of an Auth user that has been created, will lead to both functions being called.

Comment: If you can't use the user object in the function callback to distinguish the two, then what you're trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: @DougStevenson I thought I could set the directory, once data has been entered at that location of the database, I thought the functions could be invoked.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "set the directory".  Again, unless you have built some facility to discern what type of account this is, you're not going to be able to discern between the two.